# Spring Data Jpa Data fetch where parent entity has foreign key on other entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i have two entity test1 and test2

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test1")
class test1{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id",unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int Id;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn("sub_category_id")
     Test2 test2Bean;

        //Getter&Setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name="test2")
class test2{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "sub_category_id",unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    //Getter&Setters
}
```

What i need is to get name from test2 entity having sub_category_id
from test1 entity

I tried mapping using JoinCloumn as you can see but failed as give error
of foreign constraint and i don't want to change by table structure

Please Help Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Can you provide the error message ?

Comment: {com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails}

Comment: Try changing `@OneToOne()` to `@OneToOne` first, and `@JoinColumn("sub_category_id")` to `@JoinColumn(name = "sub_category_id")`

Comment: I have made these changes still no result.

Comment: And are you sure about your database ?

Comment: what to do with it let me know i"ll try them too.
To make it work anyway